# Supremum of empirical process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $\hat{F}_{n}$ is the empirical distribution function based on a sample
$(X_{1},\ldots,X_{n})$, where each $X_{i}$ has distribution function $F$.

Also, suppose that the distribution of $X_{i}$ has a smooth density $f(x)$.
Let $\xi_{p}$ be the $p^{th}$ quantile of $X_{i}$, that is, $F(\xi_{p}) = p$.

Is there anything known about the following process:
$$
\sup_{1 \leq i \leq n} \frac{\hat{F}_{n}(\xi_{i/n}) - F(\xi_{i/n})}{f(\xi_{i/n})}
$$
For example, does the above supremum go to zero in probablity at a certain rate?

I know that from the Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality that

$$
P(\sup_{x}|\hat{F}_{n}(x) - F(x)| \geq \varepsilon) \leq 2e^{-2n\varepsilon^{2}},
$$
but I don't know what happens when we divide by the density.